# How to calculate the time complexity of the following function?

Tags: c, complexity-theory

The time complexity of the following code is O(2^n), could you please explain to me why?

```
int f(int n)
{
 if (n == 1)
 return 1;
 return 1 + f(f(n-1));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this question.

Comment: You may want to prove it by induction. I assume you took some course on resolving recurrence relations. Otherwise, post it on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: What have you done so far? What are f (1), f (2), f (3), f (4), f (5)? Do you see a pattern? How many function calls will be made when you call f (1), f (2), f (3), f (4), f (5) etc. ? Again, can you see a pattern? Can you write a proof for your pattern?

Comment: Looks like I just did your homework ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, this question was now asked (and possibly answered) at [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38448/how-to-calculate-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-function).

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = n is a solution for this recurence relation

Proof:
f(n) = f(f(n-1)) + 1 = f(n-1) + 1 = (n-1) + 1 = n

Sample VBA code that verifies it:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 20
        Debug.Print i, f(i)
    Next
End Sub

Function f(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    If n = 1 Then
        f = 1
    Else
        f = 1 + f(f(n - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Since we have established that f(n) = n, we can conclude that

f(n-1) = n-1

Assuming that it takes `An` calls to get f(n), `An` being a recurrence relation:

```
An = 1 + 2 * An-1
```

- The call to calculate f(n)
- The numbers of calls necessary to calculate f(n-1) which will return n-1
- then the same number of calls to calculate f(f(n-1)) since we are calling f with n-1 again.

The solution of the recurrence relation is 2^n - 1

Answer (score 0):

Cost complexity is 2^n -1

VBA Code:

Option Explicit
Dim count As Long

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 20
        count = 0
        f i
        Debug.Print i, count
    Next
End Sub

Function f(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    count = count + 1
    If n = 1 Then
        f = 1
    Else
        f = 1 + f(f(n - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Output:

```
1   1
2   3
3   7
4   15
5   31
6   63
7   127
8   255
9   511
10  1023
11  2047
12  4095
13  8191
14  16383
15  32767
16  65535
17  131071
18  262143
19  524287
20  1048575
```

Comment: The question was *why* it's O(2^n). Your program only suggests that this claim is actually true.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I added another answer